# What kind of microphone can I use measure Head Related Transfer Functions?

Tags: binaural, hrtf

It's not for anything super-professional, I've just been learning a little more about this stuff and I wanted to measure my own.

In terms of placing microphones in my own ears, I've been assuming small lav mics would work - short of getting some sort of purpose-made thing - how accurate is this sort of thing likely to be?

Lastly, I've got some cardioid as well as some omni lavs. Which is best? I would expect it to be omni, and those are probably what I would go with if I was just going to try it blind, thought I'd check!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please update question to spell out HRTF.

Answer (score 1):

Omnis should be chosen.

And if you choose a pair instead of just one (if you can't sample-accurately reproduce the clock after placing the microphone in the other ear and doing the measurement for the same azimuth & elevation), they should be calibrated so that their response is similar (complicated stuff there).

If you choose to acquire binaural microphones, here's a list of hardware I've just published: http://blog.francois-becker.net/post/2015/04/19/Binaural-microphones-and-dummyheads

Comment: Taking a look at the link you posted, particularly the do-it-yourself ones, and the Beck Binaural Head is the creepiest thing I've seen in a while.

Comment: BTW, I'm not related to the Beck Binaural Head.

Answer (score -2):

you can try a pair of matched DPA 4060 hi-sensitivity capsules.

Comment: hi and welcome. can you please expand why you think this is a good option?

Comment: [Microphone Capsules
The Free Space Pro II uses matched DPA 4060 hi-sensitivity capsules.](http://3diosound.com/index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=33&products_id=47)

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged, as links can (and do) go stale.  As Arnoud was saying, _why_ is your suggestion a possible answer to the OP's question?  The OP was asking how accurate his current equipment would be, as well as the better of cardioid and omni lavs.  Please expand on your answer :)  You can click the 'edit' link to make edits to your original answer.